# How to convert mail server date string to nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date string form mail server like this. Thu, 31 Dec 2009 14:32:15 +0580.
I want to convert this date string to date.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   NSString *inputstring=@"Mon, 3 sep 2012 08:32:39 +0580";
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
   [dateFormatter setLenient:YES];
   NSLocale *enUS = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
   [dateFormatter setLocale:enUS];
   NSDate *result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputstring];
   NSLog(@"test==%@",result);
}
```

I am getting output null.

Excepted Output : 2012-09-03 03:02:39 +0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:  You are not trying to read the "Tue" on the string.  (Add "EEE, " to the front of your format)

Second and bigger problem:  +0580 is not a valid time zone.  There was a PHP bug a few years ago that mistakenly returned IST (+0530) as +0580.  +0580 makes no sense.  It means 5 hours and 80 minutes.  So you can do one of two things:  Either replace +0580 with +0530 before you process it **or** set the date formatter time zone to be IST and remove the +0580 from the string.

I see you accepted another answer, but that answer "works" because it fails to parse the final part and ignores the time zone.  I ran it and got **2013-07-09 08:32:38 +0000** (Which is not the same as **2013-07-09 08:32:39 +0580**)

Removing the `+` in the accepted answer's format causes the formatter to parse correctly, but you will get `null` because the timezone is invalid.  Changing the time zone to +0530 gives the expected result of **2013-07-09 03:02:39 +0000**

Comment: Thanku for your response... but i cant change the date string because iam getting that string from mail server...

Comment: I mean change it *after* you receive it.

Comment: Yah iam trying that one but iam not getting , if u don't mind can u post sample code for this one

Comment: my input string is "Tue, 9 Jul 2013 08:32:39 +0580" and i want out as nsdate like this 2013-07-09 03:02:39 +0000 ...  How can i?

Comment: Use `NSString`'s `stringByReplacingStringWithString` method after you receive it from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];`

with

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz"];`

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste the below code in your project and run, see the result

```
NSString *dateString = @"Tue, 9 Jul 2013 08:32:39 +0580";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss +zzzz"];
NSDate *dateFromString;
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"test==%@",dateFromString);
```

Comment: Allocation of `NSDate *dateFromString` is not required using `alloc` as it is already assigned memory through `dateFromString:`. So I edited your answer.

Comment: This will ignore the time zone though.  The result for me was **2013-07-09 08:32:38 +0000**  The time zone is the big problem here.

Comment: my input string is "Tue, 9 Jul 2013 08:32:39 +0580" and i want out as nsdate like this 2013-07-09 03:02:39 +0000 ... How can i?

Answer (score 1):

@Raviteja Kammila  use following code for date format like 2013-07-09 03:02:39 +0000

```
    NSString *dateString = @"Tue, 9 Jul 2013 08:32:39 +0580";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss +zzzz"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"final date : %@",date);
```

Comment: Its getting output : 2013-07-09 08:32:38 +0000 but i want 2013-07-09 03:02:39 +0000

Comment: This answer literally just changed hh to HH from a previous answer...you can throw whatever parsing format you like at the string but *it is not a valid string*

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya It's not a problem with your answer, or the previous answer.  The problem is that the issue is not addressed.  See my answer.  The string OP is receiving is not valid.

Comment: +1 @Borrrden Sorry,for not getting you. Thank you very much :)